# Why was "Forward the Foundation" unpublished?

Tags: isaac-asimov, foundation

I am looking at [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foundation_series#List_of_books_within_the_Foundation_Universe) and wondering about *Forward the Foundation* ... why was it unpublished?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Wikipedia is quoting a specific list that appears in *Prelude to Foundation*, which was published in 1988. *Forward the Foundation* wasn't published until five years later, and presumably hadn't been written yet when that list was printed.

Comment: Ahhh thanks. I would've written it "not yet published", think I'll go ahead and make that change  :-)